# sending packets from iperf packet generator in continuous mode

Tags: udp, packet, iperf

Can we send packets from iperf generator in a continuous mode? Currently, I am sending packets in a burst mode by using command

```
iperf -c 10.0.0.2 -u -b 1m -t 1
```

where u is UDP packets 1m is bandwidth (1 Mbps) and t is a time which is 1 second.

but I want to send in continuous mode.

Comment: How continuous does it have to be? I wonder if your problem would be solved by using a very large number for the time.

Comment: say one packet per second.

Comment: Let me put it another way: What are you trying to measure?

In your example, your measurement is continuous for the duration of one second. You can let iperf go on for as long as you want if you set the `-t` option to a very high value.

Comment: I am just sending UDP packets. The generator sends 87 packets in 1 second but I want to send packets per seconds i.e one packet per seconds.

Comment: I'm still wondering why you would want that :), but you could use netcat to send a packet every second: `while true; do echo "one packet" |  nc -u -c 10.0.0.2 80; sleep 1; done
`

Answer (score 11):

Time can be a floating-point value, and one special floating-point value is infinity:

```
iperf3 -c 10.0.0.2 -tinf
iperf -c 10.0.0.2 -tinf
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, simply combining iperf with the watch utility creates continuous monitoring.

```
watch iperf -c 192.168.178.21 -t2
```

Answer (score -1):

For iperf 2.0.13 use iperf -c  -b 1pps

```
CLIENT SPECIFIC OPTIONS
       -b, --bandwidth n[kmgKMG] | npps
              set target bandwidth to n bits/sec (default 1 Mbit/sec) or n packets per sec.  This may be used with TCP or UDP.  For variable loads use format mean,standard deviation
```

Bob

Comment: sorry, that's an answer to a different question.

Answer (score -1):

for iperf v3.0.11 : you can play with -w "windows size" value

Comment: the question was about continuous mode, not about window sizes.